# (C++) Error compiling project using Cinder

Tags: c++, cinder

I downloaded this project about making procedural tilemaps from github:

https://github.com/Tenjix/Sethex

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQQqRKGbNKY

Im using Visual Studio Community 2015

This project uses Cinder for the GUI, I think I've referenced everything correctly, but when i try compiling I get this error:

```
1>Imgui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cinder::gl::BufferObj::bufferData(int,void const *,unsigned int)" (?bufferData@BufferObj@gl@cinder@@QAEXHPBXI@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ImGui::Renderer::render(struct ImDrawData *)" (?render@Renderer@ImGui@@QAEXPAUImDrawData@@@z)
1>Imgui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::Vbo::create(unsigned int,int,void const *,unsigned int)" (?create@Vbo@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VVbo@gl@cinder@@@std@@IHPBXI@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ImGui::Renderer::initBuffers(unsigned int)" (?initBuffers@Renderer@ImGui@@QAEXI@Z)
1>TileSystem.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::Vbo::create(unsigned int,int,void const *,unsigned int)" (?create@Vbo@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VVbo@gl@cinder@@@std@@IHPBXI@Z)
1>Imgui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > __cdecl cinder::Clipboard::getString(void)" (?getString@Clipboard@cinder@@sa?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@std@@xz) referenced in function "public: __thiscall <lambda_13e4aa6ecc8ce3f92674e08a50ebf002>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_13e4aa6ecc8ce3f92674e08a50ebf002>@@qbe@XZ)
1>Imgui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl cinder::Clipboard::setString(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?setString@Clipboard@cinder@@SAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall <lambda_a1814c47626d98ae27b916ab376230a7>::operator()(char const *)const " (??R<lambda_a1814c47626d98ae27b916ab376230a7>@@QBEXPBD@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::GlslProg::create(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?create@GlslProg@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VGlslProg@gl@cinder@@@std@@abv?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@5@0000@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall <lambda_34aa54e458e6f253a55ff14b8affd4be>::operator()(class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path const &)const " (??R<lambda_34aa54e458e6f253a55ff14b8affd4be>@@QBEXABVpath@v1@filesystem@experimental@std@@@z)
1>TileSystem.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::GlslProg::create(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?create@GlslProg@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VGlslProg@gl@cinder@@@std@@abv?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@5@0000@Z)
1>Generator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::GlslProg::create(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?create@GlslProg@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VGlslProg@gl@cinder@@@std@@abv?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@5@0000@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall cinder::gl::TextureFont::TextureFont(class cinder::Font const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class cinder::gl::TextureFont::Format const &)" (??0TextureFont@gl@cinder@@iae@ABVFont@2@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVFormat@012@@z) referenced in function "public: static class std::shared_ptr __cdecl cinder::gl::TextureFont::create(class cinder::Font const &,class cinder::gl::TextureFont::Format const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?create@TextureFont@gl@cinder@@sa?AV?$shared_ptr@VTextureFont@gl@cinder@@@std@@ABVFont@3@ABVFormat@123@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@v?$allocator@D@2@@5@@z)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::AppMsw(void)" (??0AppMsw@app@cinder@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall tenjix::sethex::Sethex::Sethex(void)" (??0Sethex@sethex@tenjix@@QAE@XZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::~AppMsw(void)" (??1AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Sethex@sethex@tenjix@@QAE@XZ$0
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::shared_ptr __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::createWindow(struct cinder::app::Window::Format const &)" (?createWindow@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VWindow@app@cinder@@@std@@ABUFormat@Window@23@@z)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::quit(void)" (?quit@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAEXXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getFrameRate(void)const " (?getFrameRate@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UBEMXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::setFrameRate(float)" (?setFrameRate@AppMsw@app@cinder@@uaexm@Z)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::disableFrameRate(void)" (?disableFrameRate@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAEXXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::isFrameRateEnabled(void)const " (?isFrameRateEnabled@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UBE_NXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::shared_ptr __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getWindow(void)const " (?getWindow@AppMsw@app@cinder@@ube?AV?$shared_ptr@VWindow@app@cinder@@@std@@xz)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::shared_ptr __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getWindowIndex(unsigned int)const " (?getWindowIndex@AppMsw@app@cinder@@ube?AV?$shared_ptr@VWindow@app@cinder@@@std@@i@Z)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getNumWindows(void)const " (?getNumWindows@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UBEIXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::shared_ptr __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getForegroundWindow(void)const " (?getForegroundWindow@AppMsw@app@cinder@@ube?AV?$shared_ptr@VWindow@app@cinder@@@std@@xz)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::hideCursor(void)" (?hideCursor@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAEXXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::showCursor(void)" (?showCursor@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UAEXXZ)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct glm::tvec2<int,0> __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::getMousePos(void)const " (?getMousePos@AppMsw@app@cinder@@ube?AU?$tvec2@H$0A@@glm@@xz)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl cinder::app::AppMsw::initialize(class cinder::app::AppMsw::Settings *,class std::shared_ptr const &,char const *)" (?initialize@AppMsw@app@cinder@@SAXPAVSettings@123@ABV?$shared_ptr@VRenderer@app@cinder@@@std@@pbd@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl cinder::app::AppMsw::main(class std::shared_ptr const &,char const *,class std::function<void __cdecl(class cinder::app::AppMsw::Settings *)> const &)" (??$main@VSethex@sethex@tenjix@@@AppMsw@app@cinder@@SAXABV?$shared_ptr@VRenderer@app@cinder@@@std@@PBDABV?$function@$$A6AXPAVSettings@AppMsw@app@cinder@@@z@4@@z)
1>Sethex.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall cinder::app::AppMsw::launch(void)" (?launch@AppMsw@app@cinder@@MAEXXZ)
1>binary\output\Win32\Debug\Sethex.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 23 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am i missing some files maybe?

Comment: this is a linker error, you should check if you link correctly against the library

Comment: @OznOg, yes, i'm correctly referencing the libs: Properties->Linker->Input -> AdditionalDependencies: Ensys.lib;OpenGL32.lib;cinder.lib;libEGL.lib;libGLESv2.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)